# How to manage volume of flash player applications on websites with Firefox?

Tags: windows, firefox, flash, firefox-extensions, flash-player

There is some nasty video viewer that has volume around 10000% higher than normally, so visiting those webpages is very nasty experience to my delicate ears, especially when those videos start automatically after page has been loaded.

How can I control the specific flash application on that website, to turn its volume down to something I can bear with?

I have tried some plugins before to completely mute the flash players, but they never worked. Only solution I have found even remotely working, is to go to volume control on Windows and adjust the volume of Firefox program. But that will control all the webpages at same time, which isnt really a problem for me though. It would be enough if it adjusted the volume each time such a flash application is found on a webpage, and then revert back to original volume after the tab or page has been closed.

OS: Windows 7

Browser: Firefox newest

Answer (score 0):

One option you should consider is using the built in `Loudness Equalization` feature found in Windows Vista and above.

Here is one article that describes it...
http://www.howtogeek.com/115656/3-ways-to-normalize-sound-volume-on-your-pc/

and another here...
http://anderwald.info/windows/normalize-all-sound-output-in-windows-vista-and-higher/comment-page-1/

A better way would be for the feature to work on per stream basis so you could apply it on your browser only but google search didn't reveal any such method to me...

Hope that helped.

Answer (score -3):

first of all percentage is every time a partial quantity of the value 100, so there are not more then 100%

secondly if the used application (flashapp or other) dosnt provide an per application volume setting you can use the application based volume setting of your operating system if such is integrate with your os (witch is the case with windows 7). Just open the volume control window and control your volume. (Normally by double clicking the speaker icon in your system bar)

greetings treaki

PS: this are basic knowledges every computer user should have in my opinion. You should think about joining a computer course.

Comment: I think i told you i already know the volume control feature. It is not very usable since i would have to predict whether or not the next click opens a page with that annoying flash player. And even if i could magically predict that, it would be very annoying to manually change the volume back and forth all the time.